# Copy and manipulate ALT on Image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm a new visitor, and relativily new at jQuery.

I have an image with an ALT text that I would like to be shown, in the SPAN, under the image, and manipulated to replace "-" with B- and I-tags...

Current HTML:

```
<span class="alignright">
    <img src="sys/billeder/medarbejdere/tommy_stor.jpg" width="162" height="219" title="Name - Age" />
    <span></span>
</span>
```

Wanted Output

```
<span class="alignright">
    <img src="sys/billeder/medarbejdere/tommy_stor.jpg" width="162" height="219" title="Name - Age" />
    <span><b>Name</b> <i>Age</i></span>
</span>
```

I have used this jQuery to extract the ALT, and put it in the SPAN:

```
var alt = $("#hoejre p span img").attr("alt");
$("#hoejre p span span").text(alt);
```

The extraction works like a charm, but I need the SPAN:

```
...to start with "<b>"
...to replace the "-" with "</b> <i>"
...and end with "</i>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I read this right, but how about changing your last line to:

```
$("#hoejre p span span").html("<b>" + alt.replace("-", "</b> <i>") + "</i>");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$("#hoejre p span span").html('<b>'+alt.replace('-', '</b> <i>')+'</i>');
```

`replace` is just regular JavaScript, `html()` a JQuery method ([documented here](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)).

Answer (score 0):

```
var alt = $("#hoejre p span img").attr("alt");
$("#hoejre p span span").html("<b>"+alt.replace("-", "</b><i>")+"</i>");
```